# define set of properties that all my gradle projects can see

Tags: java, gradle

I have the below ext.libraries definition that I would like to expose to all of my projects that I build with gradle. How would I do this. Where can I define it so that it is globally available to my projects?

My projects structure looks as follows:

```
 --projects
        ----BaseFrameWork
        ----ProjectA
        ----ProjectB
```

**settings.gradle (projects dir)**

```
includeFlat 'BaseFramework', 'ProjectA', 'ProjectB'
```

**build.gradle (projects dir)**

```
ext.libraries = [
    lib_core:[
        ":junit:4.0:",
        ":log4j:1.2.8:",
        ":ojdbc6:",
        ":struts:1.1-tiger:"
    ],
    lib_jaxb: [
        ":jaxb-api:2.1.3:",
        ":jaxb-impl:2.1.3:"
    ]
]    

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'        
}
```

**build.gradle (BaseFramework dir)**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir  'src/java' 
println "The root project is: " + rootProject
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-nowarn'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Title": "BaseFramework", "Implementation-Version": "1")
    }
    from ('./META-INF/') {
        include 'DomainConfig.xml'
        into('META-INF')
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir dirs: "D:/myrepo"
}

dependencies {
    compile libraries.lib_commons
    compile libraries.lib_core
    compile libraries.lib_jaxb
}
```

I then try the below and get an error. It cant see my libraries property in the root build.gradle file. It also looks like it's seeing my BaseFramework project as the root??

```
D:\projects>cd BaseFramework    
D:\projects\BaseFramework>gradle build
The root project is: root project 'BaseFramework'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\prod\BaseFramework\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'BaseFramework'.
> Could not find property 'libraries' on root project 'BaseFramework'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.624 secs

D:\projects\BaseFramework>
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in your top-level `build.gradle`, outside of any section. You can then access it from any subproject.

You also need to replace `includeFlat` by `include` in `settings.gradle`, otherwise it will expect to find those directories at the same level as the `projects` directory.

`includeFlat` tells Gradle that those **sibling** directories should be considered as subprojects. In your case, `BaseFramework`, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` are not siblings of the `projects` directory, they are children.

On the other hand, `include` tells Gradle that those **child** directories should be considered as subprojects. That's what you want, so the subprojects can inherit the variables declared in `projects`.

Comment: The `ext.libraries` declaration can stay outside `allprojects`, as child projects can see the extra variables declared by parent projects. The `dependencies` block should go inside (`subprojects` is often a better fit though).

Comment: Not all subprojects have the same set of dependencies :)

Comment: I did the above and I'm still getting *cannot get property 'libraries' on extra properties extension as it does not exist*

Comment: Create a `build.gradle` file in the `projects` directory and put the `ext.libraries` declaration in it - if it is not already there.

Comment: Oh and try replacing `includeFlat` by just `include` in `settings.gradle`.

Comment: I didn't see your suggestions David. Only saw them now. The include instead of the includeFlat was the winner. I have reworked the question again to include ALL the info (like I should've done from the start) Why do you think this made the difference. Why did includeFlat make everything go haywire? You should post your comment as an answer too.

Comment: I have modified my answer and added the info about `includeFlat` vs `include`.